# Created By and last Modified By for Get pages

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

Do we have a way to identify who created the page (Created by in Get pages request) using API call? We see the properties Created By and last Modified By for Get sections. Can we get the same properties for Get pages?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the OneNote GET ~/pages API does not support the properties "CreatedBy" and "LastModifiedBy. I would recommend creating an item in UserVoice (I will upvote it ;) )

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis